# I cannot connect with database

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am new in php and codeigniter framework. I have tried to make a login page in aptana studio 3. The problem is that i could not connect with db.Every username and password i type, right or wrong, redirects me to the home page WElcome. I am sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but i am not too much into it. I would appreciate everyone who could help. Below is my code.

user.php

```
<?php
Class User extends CI_Model
{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
      $this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
      $this -> db -> from('punetor');
      $this -> db -> where('username', $username);
      $this -> db -> where('password', MD5($password));
      $this -> db -> limit(1);

      $query = $this -> db -> get();

      if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
      {
      return $query->result();
        }
      else
      {
     return false;
     }
    }
   }
   ?>
```

login_user.php

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class login extends CI_Controller
{


 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   $this->load->helper(array('form'));
   $this->load->view('login_view');
 }

}

?>
```

login_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>User Login</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>User Login</h1>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
   <form method="post"action="home_view.php">
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

verifylogin.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }



 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login_view');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('home_user', 'refresh');
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
?>
```

home_user.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login_user', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('home_user', 'refresh');
 }

}

?>
```

home_view.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your page has form. Because you're trying to create form using CodeIgniter's form helper class.

Comment: ok i'm trying to change it

Comment: it worked. thank u so so much

Comment: You're welcome friend. :)

Comment: I have another problem. The connection with database is not working. Every username and password i put it shows Welcome!